# How to pass parameter in JDBC query for creating table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to write a sql query where i want to pass the table name at run-time. Query:

```
create table mytable (time datetime, price double)
```

So, i have created a generic query :

```
create table ? (time datetime, price double)
```

and then i am passing the table name at run-time as:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
preparedStatement.setString(1, tableName);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
```

On running this code i am getting exception that my query syntax is not correct. Do we pass the parameter for creating table using some other technique?

Comment: See http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-create-a-table/

Comment: @user3145373ツ: Missing any details about getting table name from a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, prepared statements does not allow setting a table name. Mostly it only supports ? in values in DML statements (insert, update, delete, select), not DDL.

To create table, you must create a SQL string, such as

```
String s = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (col int) ";
stmt.execute(s);
```

Comment: this is my worst nightmare come true. You sure there isn't any other way?

Comment: I remember several years ago, I tried exactly the same thing with you, to DB2, Oracle, and SQLServer.

Comment: I remember that maybe a DB supports this way (I cannot remember exactly).

Comment: So I am afraid that you need to build a full String first. The purpose for prepared statement is to re-use the compiled SQL statements to enhance performance, especially for similar SQLs (For example, insert 1000 recoreds into one table). DDL is not its target, because on DB side, DDL needs many more things than DML.